# Entity Framework Serialization Queries

Tags: entity-framework-5

I m getting self referencing loop error but my question is not related to it. Its more on the reasoning

```
             try
                {
                    using (MyEntities sls = new MyEntities ())
                    {


                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, WareTypeData );
                    } var WareTypeData = sls.WareTypes;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
                }
```

In this version of code, i get the error message as *"Error getting value from 'UnauthorizedAppLists' "* and innerexception is *The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection*

The actual cause for the exception is self referencing loop which i got from the browser if i dont use the "using statement" and define the Entities variable jus like

```
  try
    {
      MyEntities sls = new MyEntities ();
```

**Question 1:**
If i use the "using statement", I m getting the error message as the object context is getting disposed at some point of time. Why it is so? I m returning the variable within the "using scope" here.

**Question 2:**
When i do the debug, breakpoints not hitting in the catch block.. Why? Is it because the it is serialization issue? Will it not be handled in Catch block? "Object getting disposed isnt the normal EF exception?"

Update:

As per Richard Request. I keep it short and simple here..

- I create IEnumerable using the line. I got that it doesnt hit the DB.
  It just formulates the query  `var WareTypeData = sls.WareTypes;`
- I create a temp variable and convert it to list using the line. It hits
  the DB `var tempVariable =WareTypeData .ToList();`
- As i pointed out,WareTypes have 1.. * many relation with one more table and in turn
  has similar relation with other table and it repeats 3 or 4 times. It
  causes "Self referencing loop issues while serilaization and i expect
  the error output as something related to "*Self referencing loop*" But
  what happens here is, i m getting ***Object Disposed error message***. I
  ensured all code blocks are within the "Using Statement only". Wanted
  to know why its happening?

P.S : I m looking for reasoning behind how things work. From the solution, i just went about using DTO classes and proxy disabling.

Answer (score 0):

Both questions come down to laziness. This is a good thing.

When you execute:

```
var WareTypeData = sls.WareTypes;
```

you are not (yet) getting all the `WareType` rows, but a lazy query that will only get those rows when it is enumerated. This allows you to chain operations:

```
WareTypeData = WareTypeData.Where(wt => wt.Kind = "Wolf");
```

When you finally enumerate the query it is translated to SQL and sent to the database for execution. This means you can perform all the filtering, joining, sorting and transforming on the database (which is designed to be good at those things).

However it also means that you need to ensure that the enumeration takes place while the context still exists. In you case it is only happening after your function returns which destroys the context. Thus the query fails.

To fix ensure you enumerate the query to actually execute the SQL and get the data within the using block:

```
var WareTypeData = sls.WareTypes.ToArray();
```

Depending on the type of application it might make more sense to tie the context's lifetime to some object instance more associated with the overall logical operation to make this easier (eg. in an ASP.NET MVC web application the lifetime of the controller).

Comment: Thanks @Richard for your response. In fact , i tried it earlier but still it doesnt make any difference in terms of error display:( btw, i m using ASP.NET Web API

Comment: @TechQuery In that case there is more going on than you've shown in the question: please update with a short, complete re-create.

Comment: @TechQuery Not enough: need to know how the result of the query is being used and how the entity types are defined. (Might be an issue with lazy loaded association properties.)